# Azure Devops : Replace variable in list with unknown order

Tags: azure, pipeline

We are running a build pipeline in azure DevOps. After the build we deploy the stuff and substitute variables in JSON files.
I have a problem substituting a variable in a list of equal objects. My son looks like this:

```
"Friends": [
      { "Name": "John",
        "Phone": "12345678"
      },

      { "Name": "Frank",
        "Phone": "12235578"
      },

      { "Name": "Bill",
        "Phone": "13790678"
      }

   ]
```

I can substitute Franks phone using the path: Friends.1.Phone

What should I do, if the order of "Friends" is not determined and I can not use the index?

I searched for the azure plugin "variable substitution condition" but I couldn't find any useful task.

Comment: I assume you are able to use bash or PowerShell script to reach this goal. and pass the output to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a powershell task and use Convertfrom-Json command

```
$Json = @'
{
"Friends": [
      { "Name": "John",
        "Phone": "12345678"
      },

      { "Name": "Frank",
        "Phone": "12235578"
      },

      { "Name": "Bill",
        "Phone": "13790678"
      }

   ]
}
'@

$result = $Json | ConvertFrom-Json
$result.Friends[0].Phone='12345'
$result | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4
```

This will change 'John' phone number.
Answer 2:

```
$result = $Json | ConvertFrom-Json 
$result.Friends | % {if($_.name -eq 'john'){$_.phone=98765}}
$result | ConvertTo-Json -depth 10
```

Comment: I have to change the phone without knowing the position of John inside the list. For this I can't use an index. I am looking for a mean like:   If (name == John) phone=xxx

Comment: I have updated my answer changing the value by condition.